# ChaiJS Should - test for empty string

Tags: javascript, node.js, chai, should.js

According to docs on the [shouldJS](https://github.com/visionmedia/should.js/) site I should be able to do this:

```
''.should.be.empty();
```

The [ChaiJS](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#empty) site doesn't have an example with *should* syntax, but it lists it for *expect* and it seems that the above example would work.

However this yields:

```
TypeError: Property 'empty' of object #<Assertion> is not a function
```

What is syntax for the Chai lib `empty()` with *should* style?

Comment: **See Also**: [`not.empty()` assertion](https://github.com/chaijs/chai/issues/323)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just remove the parens - instead of `empty()`, use `empty`:

```js
''.should.be.empty;
```

**Further Reading**: [Docs on `Empty`](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_empty)

Comment: or ```expect('').to.be.empty```